# Pass 2D array in querystring to JSP

Tags: jsp, query-string

I would like to create a 2D array in the query string and pass it to JSP. I could append strings, but I couldn't find the syntax to append two dimensional arrays.

Example:

> http://localhost:8080/queryWithQueryString?twodArray[0][0]=storeid&twodArray[0][1]=101

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use that as-is. The parameter name will arrive literally in exact that form. JSP doesn't have any special treatment for this (unlike for example PHP). So you'd need to parse it *yourself*.

```
String[][] twodArray = new String[1][];
twodArray[0] = new String[2];
twodArray[0][0] = request.getParameter("twodArray[0][0]");
twodArray[0][1] = request.getParameter("twodArray[0][1]");
```

It's probably easier to use standard HTTP conventions for multiple parameter names.

> http://localhost:8080/queryWithQueryString?twodArray[0]=storeid&twodArray[0]=101

with

```
String[][] twodArray = new String[1][];
twodArray[0] = request.getParameterValues("twodArray[0]");
```

It's probably also easier to use a `List<String[]>` instead of `String[][]` as a `List` can be dynamically expanded. This is helpful if you don't know the amount of items beforehand.

```
List<String[]> twodArray = new ArrayList<String[]>();

for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    String[] values = request.getParameterValues("twodArray[" + i + "]");
    if (values == null) break;
    twodArray.add(values);
}
```